# Update: Http status 500 - Scriptlets are disallowed here

Tags: java, jsp

I have two jsps, LoginSuccess.jsp, and acctinfo.jsp.
In LoginSuccess.jsp, I am setting an attribute called Username with a valid username value in   LoginSuccess.jsp

What I am trying to achieve is: when the user clicks on the hyperlink, it transfers control to acctinfo.jsp via the following statement  
where url = "acctinfo.jsp"

In acctinfo.jsp. I extract the Username variable out of the session. I have an input field called UserName whose value I wish to set as value="<%= userName %>"

What I like to see is the input field populated with this userName value. Instead the JSP compiler complains with the following exception:

```
HTTP Status 500 - /acctinfo.jsp(36,66) Scripting elements ( &lt;%!, &lt;jsp:declaration, &lt;%=,   &lt;jsp:expression, &lt;%, &lt;jsp:scriptlet ) are disallowed here.
```

Here is the code for LoginSuccess.jsp:

```
<body>
<%
    System.out.println("LoginSuccess.jsp: Entered LoginSuccess.jsp");
    String username = request.getParameter("Username");
    System.out.println("LoginSuccess.jsp: User Name from the request is: " + username);
    session.setAttribute("Username", username);

    String url2 = "acctinfo.jsp";
    System.out.println("LoginSuccess.jsp: URL is: " + url);
    //session.setAttribute("CustomerName", customerName);
 %>
    **<h3>Login successful.</h3>
    <a href=<%= url2 %>>Proceed to Account Information Page</a>**
```

Here is the code for acctinfo.jsp:

```
  <%
     String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("Username");
   %>

 <form name="ViewBalance" action="" method="POST">
     <p>UserName: <input type=text NAME=UserName value="<%= userName %>">

 </form>
```

---

**Here is the correct code: the "hyperlink to acctinfo.jsp" line  is indeed outside my scriplet block, and I still see this problem.** The JSP compiler is still complaining it wont allow scripting elements here.
What am I doing wrong here? I would like someone to throw more light on this issue

---

Update: I solved the problem by the use of JSP EL and doing away with Scriptlets.

In the LoginSuccess.jsp:
I set the attribute Username in the session as follows:

```
session.setAttribute("Username", username);
```

In my acctinfo.jsp I did:

```
<p>UserName: <input type=text NAME=UserName value="${sessionScope.Username}"></p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are writing HTML code inside your scriptlets - you have to close the scriptlet after you finish writing Java code.

This should do it - LoginSuccess.jsp:

```
<body>
<%
    System.out.println("LoginSuccess.jsp: Entered LoginSuccess.jsp");
    String username = request.getParameter("Username");
    System.out.println("LoginSuccess.jsp: User Name from the request is: " + username);
    session.setAttribute("Username", username);

    String url2 = "acctinfo.jsp";
    System.out.println("LoginSuccess.jsp: URL is: " + url);
    //session.setAttribute("CustomerName", customerName);
%>

<h3>Login successful.</h3>
<a href=<%= url2 %>>Proceed to Account Information Page</a>
```